# Why in some linux distribution systemd services are enabled by default and in others it is not?

Tags: linux, debian, arch-linux, systemd

I have noticed that after a package installation via apt-get in Debian the service in systemd is enabled by default. However, in other distributions, such as Arch Linux, the service in that package is disabled by default.

My questions are:

1. On what does this behavior depend? Is it some setting in the package manager or the package itself decides whether it is enabled or not?

I mean on Debian it looks like `systemctl enable docker.service` was executed after installation. And on Arch-linux the `docker.service` is disabled.

2. How can I change it?

Comment: There is not much option about avoiding systemd using Linux except if using Slackware or other small distros like AntiX

Comment: http://without-systemd.org/wiki/index.php/Linux_distributions_without_systemd

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro My question is not about systemd itself, but about services thar systemd manages.

Comment: Arch assumes you know what you are doing; Debian is agnostic on that front.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[As the systemd preset blurb states](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Preset/), this is a policy choice made by distributors:

> On Fedora all services stay off by default, so that installing a package will not cause a service to be enabled (with some exceptions). On Debian all services are immediately enabled by default, so that installing a package will cause its service(s) to be enabled right-away.

In theory, systemd distributions use the preset system for deciding whether a service should be enabled after package installation, running `systemctl preset` rather than `systemctl enable` in package post-install maintenance scripts; and applying your local overrides to the distribution policy is as simple as creating your own higher priority presets in `/etc/systemd/system-preset/`.  (The Arch doco is rather misleading, here.  The usual case is to create an individual local preset file that addresses specific services.)

In practice, some systemd distributions do not use the preset system for this, and applying your local overrides to systemd is a matter of employing the distributions' own mechanisms, if they even actually have such.

## Further reading

- Raphaël Hertzog (2014-12-08). *[deb-systemd-helper does not respect systemd Preset files](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=772555)*.  Debian Bug #772555.
- "[Enable installed units by default](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Enable_installed_units_by_default)". *systemd*. Arch wiki.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) On what does this behavior depend? Is it some setting in package manager or the package itself decides whether it is enabled or not?

Each distribution may use different package managers like apt in Debian or pacman in Arch Linux. This requires software developers and/or package maintainers to prepare a package in various (often incoherent) ways. Such differences may be related to the settings in the package, but sometimes the package may be prepared without assumption that systemd will be used on the target system.

> 2) How can I change it?

Find out how the specific package for your distribution is prepared and maintaned, and who is responsible for it. If it's open source, there's a chance that you will be able to modify behaviour by yourself in the installation sources. You may also contact someone from the software developers/maintainers community to suggest changes.

Comment: for Debian, relevant link: [Debian Policy 9.3.3.1. Managing the links](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#managing-the-links) "The default behaviour is to enable autostarting your package's daemon." Since it's the policy manual, it describes choices made. (might not be up to date with systemd)

Comment: @A.B Thanks for answer. That's exactly what I was looking for.