# Preventing auto-start when installing services on Debian

Tags: debian, systemd

What can I do to prevent that a service starts on install?

When installing `zerotier-one` manually, i.e. using

```
apt install zerotier-one
```

it is both *enabled* (equivalent of `systemctl enable zerotier-one`) and *started* (equivalent of `systemctl start zerotier-one`) automatically. Is there some way of preventing this behviour?

Looking at the control file in the `.deb` the package is built using `dh_systemd_enable` to enable it, and `dh_installinit` to start it. Neither of the manpages for these two pieces of debhelper mention anything about how to prevent enable/start though.

Comment: here's what you're looking for https://serverfault.com/questions/567474/how-can-i-install-packages-without-starting-their-associated-services

Answer (score 3):

For a one off installation, you can prevent a service from being started by [masking](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#mask%20UNIT%E2%80%A6) it beforehand:

```
sudo systemctl mask zerotier-one
```

(See [this recent `debian-devel` thread on “not starting a daemon upon installation”](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2020/03/msg00051.html) for related discussion, including the paucity of documentation in a Debian-specific context.)

To define a more comprehensive policy, you can use [systemd presets](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Preset/), which are designed explicitly for this; for a single service you could create a preset containing only

```
disable zerotier-one.service
```

Comment: The _proper_ systemd way is of course presets, not masks, with the maintainer scripts using `systemctl preset` instead of `systemctl enable`.  Last that I checked, this was rarely used by Debian packages and did not really work in Debian if one used debhelper.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462321/5132

Comment: @JdeBP indeed, presets are another option, I’ll update my answer. They are supported in Debian, *via* `deb-systemd-helper`, see [#772555](https://bugs.debian.org/772555) for details.