How to start openssh server at first run with public key authentication only?
When we do
sudo apt install -y openssh-server

it installs by default with password authentication which could be unsafe if the password is too easy, and it already starts listening for connections.
Is there a way to run at first run with public key authenticartion only?

Write the sshd_config before installing.

Related: https://superuser.com/questions/203827/ https://askubuntu.com/questions/74061/  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592271/

Similar to what Panki suggested you can add your customization in sshd_config.d before installing.
Debian's sshd_config starts with an Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf.
It is in general a good idea to place changes to the default config in sshd_config.d instead because it avoids conflicts if sshd_config changes.
So a simple
# mkdir -p /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d
# echo 'PasswordAuthentication no' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/auth.conf

before installing could solve your problem.

that is dangerous as it has no other special configs self generated by  sshd

I'm not sure what you mean by special configs. It should work fine for Debian since that default config starts by including configs from this directory which is usually empty and ssh uses the value from the first time an option was specified.

@GuerlandoOCs I'm curious to know why this is dangerous.  I use roughly the same code in my startup scripts.
